# get path of Array (PHP)

Tags: php

i have an array input like this ..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42
        )

    [**42**] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 14
        )

    [**14**] => Array
        (
            [0] => 317
        )

    [317] => Array
        (
            [0] => 319
        )

    [**12**] => Array
        (
            [0] => 306
            [1] => 307
        )

    [307] => Array
        (
            [0] => 311
        )

    [306] => Array
        (
            [0] => 309
        )
)
```

and i want to get result array like bellow :

$paths[]=array(42,12,306,309);

$paths[]=array(42,12,307,311);

$paths[]=array(42,14,317,319);

**see array input**

- root in array input = 42 (index of array 0)
- 42 have child = 12, 14
- 12 have child = 306, 307
- 14 have child = 317
- 306 have child =  309
- 307 have child = 311
- 317 have child = 319

like this..

and output array insert into $paths

$paths[0]=array(42,12,306,309);

$paths[1]=array(42,12,307,311);

$paths[2]=array(42,14,317,319);

Comment: What logic is `array(42,12,306,309)` based on?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question in the current form.  Can you confirm the code sections are what you intended?

Comment: Could you try to explain a little more in detail what the problem or what you're trying to achieve? $paths[] pushes the other side of the equation into the array. I can't really follow the pattern you have in there atm.…

Comment: I think it's $a[0][0] == 42, $a[42][0] == 12, $a[12][0] == 306, $a[306][0] == 309, $a[309] doesn't exist. So, in short, the array represents a tree, and he wants $paths to be an array of all paths from the root to a leaf.

Comment: sorry if I can't explain properly.. wait few minutes i want to edit my question and coding.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function getpaths($arr, $node = 0){
    $path = array();
    foreach($arr[$node] as $next){
        if(isset($arr[$next])){
            $p = getpaths($arr, $next);
            foreach($p as $q){
                $path[] = array_merge(array($next), $q);
            }
        }else{
            $path[] = array($next);
        }
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Invoke as `$path = getpaths($arr);`

Comment: thanks Mark but, when i try this function got error "Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)". can you print your full coding and output..

Comment: @Kawah: sorry, made a typo when I added the default parameter; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

this is coding by Mark E, and i add one line coding to solve "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)"

like this...

```
function getpaths($arr, $node = 0){
    $path = array();
    foreach($arr[$node] as $next){
        if(isset($arr[$next])){
            $node = $next;// adding by me
            $p = getpaths($arr, $node);
            foreach($p as $q){
                $path[] = array_merge(array($next), $q);
            }
        }else{
            $path[] = array($next);
        }
    }
    return $path;
}
```

thanks Mark E